# Getting `signed_request_invalid_format` when trying to access GCP bucket content via Cloud CDN

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-cdn

I am using signed cookies, to access some restricted files stored in GCP bucket via Cloud CDN. I am using the below function to sign the cookie:

```
signCookie(urlPrefix: string, keyName: string, key: string, expires: number) {
    // Base64url encode the url prefix
    const urlPrefixEncoded = Buffer.from(urlPrefix).toString('base64url');

    // Input to be signed
    const input = `URLPrefix=${urlPrefixEncoded}:Expires=${expires}:KeyName=${keyName}`;

    // Create bytes from given key string.
    const keyBytes = Buffer.from(key, 'base64');

    // Use key bytes and crypto.createHmac to produce a base64 encoded signature which is then escaped to be base64url encoded.
    const signature = createHmac('sha1', keyBytes).update(input).digest('base64url');

    // Adding the signature on the end if the cookie value
    const signedValue = `${input}:Signature=${signature}`;

    return signedValue;
  }
```

The cookie is getting generated and getting sent through to the CDN, but it fails with status 403, and the following message comes up:

```
Error: Forbidden
Your client does not have permission to get URL ********/sample.pdf from this server.
```

On checking, the load balancer logs, I get this `statusDetails: "signed_request_invalid_format"`. Unfortunately, this message is not present in the list of error messages listed [here](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/https-logging-monitoring#failure-messages). Can anyone help me in pointing out the issue, is the signed cookie invalid? Is there any error in the cookie generation logic?

Comment: Go through the following doc for required information:
1) https://medium.com/@reisfeld/google-cloud-cdn-best-practice-ed643558120e
Let me know in case of any issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is for the people using `express` for their server. The `sign cookie` function generates the cookie as expected, the issue comes when setting the cookie. When we set the cookie like this:

```
response.cookie('Cloud-CDN-Cookie', cookieValue, {
          httpOnly: true,
          expires: new Date(cookieExpiryTime),
});
```

The cookie value gets URI encoded, and as a result of this all the reserved characters for the URL like `=`, get replaced with `%3D` and so on. This breaks the cookie structure, as declared in the documentation:

```
URLPrefix=$BASE64URLECNODEDURLORPREFIX:Expires=$TIMESTAMP:KeyName=$KEYNAME:Signature=$BASE64URLENCODEDHMAC
```

To fix this pass an extra encode function while setting cookie:

```
response.cookie('Cloud-CDN-Cookie', cookieValue, {
          httpOnly: true,
          expires: new Date(cookieExpiryTime),
          encode: val => val
});
```

Hopefully, it will save you time.